# Why can't connect to my Database on Vercel using Next JS and a MySQL cloud service?

Tags: mysql, database, next.js, vercel

I have a Vercel URL for my project and it works at least on the front end. I have created a `cloudclusters` MySQL database instance and uploaded my DB and Tables and can access them in Workbench.
It will not seem to connect on my Next JS website.
My `lib/db.js` file looks like this:

```
const db = mysql({
  config: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_SCHEMA,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  },
})
```

And I get this error on my site.

```
theres been an err {
  error: Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [Tried IP and Host here]:10001 <-Port Given to me
      at connect (/var/task/node_modules/serverless-mysql/index.js:80:15)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
      at async Object.query (/var/task/node_modules/serverless-mysql/index.js:182:5)
      at async query (/var/task/dist/serverless/pages/api/bets/dailypick.js:454:18)
      at async module.exports.QEqJ.__webpack_exports__.default (/var/task/dist/serverless/pages/api/bets/dailypick.js:266:10)
      at async apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js:8:1)
      at async /var/task/dist/serverless/pages/api/dailypick.js:137:387,
  statement: SQLStatement {
    strings: [
      "SELECT ..... LIMIT 8'
    ],
    values: [ 1673494606.974 ]
  }
}
```

I don't know why I can access it in Workbench but then using the same details on my Vercel instance it won't work.

Is there any suggestions or things I can do to Debug it better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok tech support has help me find that I was missing port here

```
const db = mysql({
  config: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_SCHEMA,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.PORT
  },
})
```